# TextField/TextFormField keeps displaying the beginning of input string when the input string doesn't fit in the text field entirely

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to display the end of the input string when the input doesn't fit in the `TextField` anymore.

[image]

As seen in the above screen recording, as soon as the input text gets big enough to not fit in the `TextField`, the view is stuck at the beginning of the field. **I want to somehow keep displaying the end of the text (as the input gets bigger) and scrollable to the beginning (the exact opposite of what it is now).** Is this possible?

This is my code:

```dart
Consumer(
  builder: (context, ref, _) {
    current.text = ref.watch(historyProvider.state).state;
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: TextField(
        toolbarOptions: const ToolbarOptions(
          copy: true,
          selectAll: true,
        ),
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
        controller: current,
        showCursor: false,
        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        cursorColor: Colors.transparent,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 28, color: Color(0xFF7F7FA5)),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one----

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: 100),
          child: TextField(
            maxLines: 1,
            // controller and etc.
          ),
        ),
      )
```